# Can being categorized as a "US resident" by the bank make me a tax resident in CA or US?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, california

According to [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/substantial-presence-test), I was never a US **tax** resident.

But there is a US bank that thinks I'm a resident in the US. I didn't update my info after leaving. I did fill out W8. I also filled out after leaving, not sure if they received my fax.

Can being categorized as a "US resident" by the bank make me a tax resident in CA or US? Directly or indirectly.

I don't want to face any surprises in the future

Answer (score 5):

Whatever the bank thinks about your status doesn’t matter for taxes; worst case would be that if they trigger something, you have to prove to the IRS that you’re not taxable in the US. However, the chances for that are infinitesimally small.
What *could* happen is that the bank could hold back parts of any interest or dividends you get through them because they think you owe taxes on it. If you don’t get any income through that bank that cannot happen obviously.

Comment: Thanks, are you able to link a source for that? Just to have a piece of mind